# How do I write a protocol over String types?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to write a protocol for String types:

```
defprotocol MyString do
  def from(data)
end

defimpl MyString, for: String do
  def from(string) do
    String.replace(string, ",", "-")
  end
end
```

This compiles, but when I try to call `MyString.from` on a string, I get

```
iex> MyString.from("foo,")

protocol MyString not implemented for "foo,", This protocol is implemented for: String
```

I get this error if I implement the protocol for `String.t`, `String.Chars`, etc. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure which version of Elixir you're using, but in 1.9 the error message is more helpful: `(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol MyString not implemented for "foo," of type BitString. This protocol is implemented for the following type(s): String`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the list of supported types for protocols here: 
https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Protocol.html

You can use `BitString` for the protocol you're building.

Comment: What is a `BitString` vs a `String.t()`?

Comment: @dopatraman BitString is just a sequence of bits.  A binary is a sequence of bytes, so it's a subset of BitString where there are always 8 bit chunks.  A String is just a UTF-8 encoded binary.

The docs here explain with some examples: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#binaries-and-bitstrings